# Can not access response data from express server in React app

Tags: json, node.js, reactjs, express, redux

In my React app, I am trying to access the error returned from this bit of server code.

```
  User.findByUsername(req.body.username)
    .then((foundUsername) => {
      if (foundUsername) {
        return res.status(422)
          .json({
            error: 'This username is not available.'
          });
      }
```

Here is the action creator on the client side

```
export const signupUser = ({ displayName, email, password, username }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.post(`${API_URL}/signup`, { displayName, email, password, username })
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });
        localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token);
        browserHistory.push('/');
      })
      .catch((res) => {
        console.log(res.data.error);
      });
  };
};
```

What I can't seem to figure out is that I can access `res.data.token` in my `then` case but can not get hold of `res.data.error` in my `catch` case even though I can see the response come through in the network tab on chrome.

This is what I get if I log `res` to the console in the `catch` case

> Error: Request failed with status code 422
>       at createError (eval at 150 (bundle.e3597bf….js:39), :15:15)
>       at settle (eval at 258 (bundle.e3597bf….js:125), :18:12)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (eval at 147 (bundle.e3597bf….js:7), :77:7)

logging `res` in `then` gives me my desired object. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The fields { displayName, email, password, username } are correct? May not be `${API_URL}/signup/`? Do you need a token Authorization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two keys in the res object.

`config` and `response`

And the error message you are looking for is in `res.response.data.error`

Comment: Thanks! Got it working. Guess I was confused because I could access `res.data` directly in the success case